# Выбор форума для Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Нужно создать форум на Wordpress.
Встала задача, о том какой именно форум подключать и какие подводные камни могут быть.
Сайт не большой в принципе, думал сначала о phpbb и или vbulletin но они слишком большие, по функционалу, там как я понял на базе их можно и сам сайт создать...
Мне нужно что то маленькое компактное и что бы были все основные функции, назначение модераторов и т д. Смотрел в сторону bbpress но как я понял он интегрируется с wordpress, может ли как то он влиять потом на нагрузку ?

Answer (score 1):

Мой совет: bbpress. bbpress - плагин от разработчиков ядра wordpress. Ни кто другой как не разработчики самого движка лучше всех знают свое детище. Что вы имеете под:

> может ли как то он влиять потом на нагрузку ?

Все плагины так, или иначе влияют на производительность сайта на wordpress

Comment: Спасибо ! я просто не знал что это форум, созданный разработчиками ! Просто мне советовали всякие интеграции, мосты, и т д, на базе vbulletin, phpbb, почему то мне показалось это не правильным, так как я не собираюсь делать два мега-портала, просто обычный средне-посещяемый сайт с формум, но что бы функционал не урезался. Но как я понял, все хорошо. Спасибо.

Comment: Рад помочь! Обращайтесь.